# How to reference an element in a list from another list with with the same class (the class is a variable)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two lists on a website. Each element has a corresponding class in the other list. Click an element in the dl, and the ul element will add the new class. I thought something like this would do it, but apparently not:

```
$('dl dt').click(function () {
    var classname = $(this).attr('class');
    $('dl dt[class~=classname]').click(function() {
        $("ul li").removeClass('active');
        $('ul li[class~=classname]').addClass('active');
    });
})
```

I feel pretty dumb because this seems super easy to accomplish, but I can't quite get it. Forgive me if I missed an obvious answer elsewhere on the site; I looked for a while and couldn't find anything.

Comment: `$(this).attr('class')` will return all the elements classes, if there are more than one? And you're not concentanating the variable into the selector, but you're looking for an element with the actual classname "classname" !

Comment: Can you show your (relevant) HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the selector:

```
$('dl dt[class~="'+classname+'"]').click(function() {
    $("ul li").removeClass('active');
    $('ul li[class~="'+classname+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Like adeneo said, if you have more than one class, this will return all classes!

Comment: Ah. I knew it was something stupid like that that I missed. Thanks. And thanks adeneo.